# Can't find my github account in ANY search

Tags: git, github, web

I can't find my github account(https://github.com/ibanezn04) in any search(Google, Bing, Yahoo, Yandex) as well as any of my repositories(https://www.google.ru/search?q=github+ibanezn04&oq=github+iba&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60l3j69i57j69i59.3548j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).
I got some reps and all of them have master branch(so robots.txt does nothing with this). Also, my github account **CREATED FEW MONTH AGO** and i tried this https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url and it did't work as well.

P.S. i read all of questions on SO about it and none them was helpful.

Comment: No one links to your repositories so search engines consider them unimportant.

Comment: @choroba my friend's account is almost the same, but i can google it.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub offers some advice regarding "[Search engine optimization for GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/search-engine-optimization-for-github-pages/)".

For for any other pages, Google alone decides of what it indexes.

You still can force Google to consider your GitHub account page by entering its URL inn the [Google search console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?pli=1).